# Why use `Propagation.REQUIRED` over `Propagation.NESTED`?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

With Spring, by default transactions use `Propogation.REQUIRED`, but this seems like a rather odd choice to me. If we ignore the existence of transactions, then it's a very normal pattern to catch an exception, and implement a fallback. E.g. in it's very basic form:

```java
public void doSomethingFirst() {}
public void doSomethingElse() {}

public void doSomethingWithFallback() {
    this.doSomething();
    try {
        this.doSomethingElse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.fallback();
    }
}
```

However, `Propagation.REQUIRED` breaks this:

```java
public void doSomethingFirst() { }
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void doSomethingElse() { }

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void doSomethingWithFallback() {
    this.doSomethingFirst();
    try {
        this.doSomethingElse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.fallback();
    }
}
```

Now if `doSomethingElse` fails, it will mark the transaction as rollback only. Even though we have a perfectly fine fallback, the entire transaction will be rolled back and there's nothing we can do to stop this.

The "fix" for this is to use `NESTED` instead of `REQUIRED` (at least in the `doSomethingElse`):

```java
public void doSomethingFirst() { }
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
public void doSomethingElse() { }

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
public void doSomethingWithFallback() {
    this.doSomethingFirst();
    try {
        this.doSomethingElse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.fallback();
    }
}
```

Now, we're using savepoints, and if `doSomethingElse` fails it will only rollback `doSomethingElse`.

To me it looks like `NESTED` is the behaviour that we almost always want, and I'm struggling to come up with *any* use case where `REQUIRED` would be preferred. `REQUIRED` prohibits the caller from recovering from errors, which is normally a bad idea.

But given that `REQUIRED` is the default, and that `NESTED` is barely ever used, surely there must be some reason why we should use `REQUIRED` over `NESTED`.

In what cases should we prefer `REQUIRED` over `NESTED`?

Comment: The `@Transactional` on the `doSomethingElse` is useless. Not every database supports savepoints, whereas all of them support `REQUIRED`. Next to that it is the default for transactions for EJBs as well and Spring has aligned with that since its inception. Also what you consider a basic practice (i.e. a fallback) isn't that basic or common. When you write something it either fails or succeeds, I don't want to do something else. If you really wanted you could do that in a new transaction instead of using savepoints as well.

Comment: The `@Transactional` on `doSomethingElse` is definitely not useless. `doSomethingElse` might perform multiple operations that require a transaction, and might be used in more than one context. And in any sufficiently complex system, you'll definitely use fallbacks where appropriate. A new transaction has entirely different characteristics though, this is not a replacement for nested at all

Comment: Regardless though, I'm getting dragged in the details, but it's missing the point. The question is when `REQUIRED` should be preferred over `NESTED`, and in your comment you addressed this with DB support only. So let's rephrase it a little bit different: if your DB supports savepoints, why use REQUIRED over NESTED?

Comment: Your question is about the default, that has been answered because it follows the default EJB behavior and that not all dbs support this. Also what you think is a common usecase isn't so common as you think. Finally most projects want an all or nothing operation not an all or partial operation which you would get with NESTED.